# How to encrypt web.config and use it in Asp.net mvc5 project?

Tags: encryption, asp.net-mvc-5, web-config

I want to know how to encrypt web.config in asp.net project?

and how can decrypt it?can asp.net decrypt it at run time or some process have to be did to decrypt the file when launching website?

Comment: There are quite a few examples of doing this available doing a Google search.  Have you tried any of those yet?

Comment: yes I'v tried all structures became in stackoverflow and msdn, even i can encypt my web.config but becuase i have shared host for my website when i upload the encrypted web.config the website is not more responsive.can you say me how to decrypt it in code not in command prompt?In some forums said that asp can decrypt at run time...do you know how? @OlaEkdahl

Answer (score 1):

for example asp.net project MVC-

you have already .net framework in your system where you are hosting IIS, and the credentials of your web.config is correct i believe.

```
1- open CMD as administrator
2- type "cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319" and enter
3- now you need to know the web.config location, example: "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test"
```

now for encrypting and decrypting:

```
4- on CMD
  for encrypting : 
        ASPNET_REGIIS -pef "connectionStrings" "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test"
  for decrypting:
        ASPNET_REGIIS -pdf "connectionStrings" "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test"
```

check your site and let me know if you face any issue: